# Sending extras to BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I have an Activity that runs the following code (time and interval are defined):

```
Intent buzzIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), BuzzReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, buzzIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
buzzIntent.putExtra("interval", interval);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, interval * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
```

and a BroadcastReceiver that has the following onReceive:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {
        int interval = intent.getIntExtra("interval", -1);
        <... more code ...>
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but the intent.getIntExtra() returns -1 (which isn't the value of interval in the Activity, I checked), so for some reason the BroadcastReceiver isn't getting the extras that I store into the intent in the Activity.

I've tried a ton of different things but nothing seems to work.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver/14612215#14612215

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Set flag `FILL_IN_DATA` while creating pending intent as below:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, buzzIntent, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
```

You should receive extras in broadcast receiver after this change.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling `buzzIntent.putExtra()` **before** you pass `buzzIntent` to `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try following code

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
int interval= bundle.getInt("interval", -1);
```

instead of

```
int interval = intent.getIntExtra("interval", -1);
```

Comment: Tried that, except using intent.getExtras(), but interval was still -1.  getIntent() didn't exist.

Comment: Updated the code are you sure that you are not sending a null value from intent

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  I can run intent.getExtras() then getInt() or even getIntExtra() from the Activity and I get the correct value.