# BroadcastReceiver intent does not receive extras

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have very strange problem.

I am sending broadcast and setting some extras but receiver is not getting them :

Sending :

```
private void notifyAboutDownload(String reference, Context ctx) {
    Intent i = new Intent(InitialActivity.ACTION_PACKAGE);
    i.setAction(InitialActivity.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLEATED);
    i.putExtra(InitialActivity.DOWNLOAD_ID, reference);

    ctx.sendBroadcast(i);

}
```

And receiving :

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String downloadID =   intent.getExtras().getString(InitialActivity.DOWNLOAD_ID);

        Log.i(TAG, "downloadID :  "+ downloadID);
    }
};
```

For some reason downloadID is null. Any hints?

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216177/sending-extras-to-broadcastreceiver

Comment: @user1281750 unfortunately it did not work

Comment: instead of using String downloadID =   intent.getExtras().getString(InitialActivity.DOWNLOAD_ID); use this      String downloadID =intent.getStringExtra(InitialActivity.DOWNLOAD_ID);

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!!  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14571564/android-pendingintent-extras-not-received-by-broadcastreceiver/14612215#14612215

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your intent like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyReceiver.class);
```